# Computer starts normally, then the screen freezes suddenly

Tags: display, motherboard

As the title mentions, when it freezes, it displays replicated portions of whatever is on the screen at that time.

Here is an example of a screen shot that i took.
[image: Screen shot]

Even if i am in the BIOS, it would freeze. and display portions of whatever is on the BIOS.!

Comment: IT is a Compaq presario Q5300F pc,  Processor: Amd Sempron le-1300, 2 GB DDR3, 320 Gb Harddrive.....Even when I load mini xp, from hirens, I still get the same problem, I used different monitors, different, vga cables, I resetted the Bios...And still same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar display issues in the past that were usually fixed by replacing some capacitors on either the video card or on the motherboard.

This link has been helpful to me - [How to identify bad capacitors](http://www.badcaps.net/pages.php?vid=5)

Cheers,